# Highlighting or marking property using node id in leaflet?

Tags: openstreetmap, leaflet

I am working on openstreetmap using leaflet.js, I found some difficulties in highlighting a way(road) using it's node ID of OSM data.

I need to know is it possible or not?

Comment: The answer to "I need to know if it's possible or not" is: [Yes](https://web.archive.org/web/20160527013035/http://homepage.ntlworld.com/jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/questions-with-yes-or-no-answers.html) . If this is not the answer you expected, I recommend you should read https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and reformulate your question.

Answer (score 3):

If you display only OSM **tiles**, remember that these are only images, so you will not be able to match node id's nor to change how they are rendered (you cannot "highlight" them).

You would need to retrieve the vectorial data of these ways / roads and display them as paths (e.g. `L.polyline`), with which you can associate metadata like the node id, and change their style to highlight them.